# splitting a column in two separate fields

Tags: bash, awk

for making a summary
I have a CSV file which is transformed to .DAT. I have an AWK file which is supposing to do the mapping of the DAT file. The code from the AWK file is the one below.

The content of the DAT file looks like this (tab separated):

```
ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME VALUE COMMENT
P3 Y6-8 ACT FG F 2011 1297
P4 Y3-4 EMP FG M 2011 6940 bd
P1 Y7-9 GRT FG F 2011 0 c
```

What I have to do is the following:

1. COMMENT columns must be splitted in two different fields: STRING_COM and STRING_STATUS - done
2. VALUE column should be renamed in "NUMB" - done
3. keep the headers together with the columns order - done

**NOT DONE**

```
4.  if the VALUE is ":" then NUMB is null
    if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "c" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c"
    if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "u" then NUMB is null and STRING_STATUS is "u"
    if the VALUE is "14,385" and COMMENT "d" then NUMB is "14385" and STRING(both) is null
    if the VALUE is "14,385" and COMMENT "du" then NUMB is "14385" and STRING_STATUS is "u"
    if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "cd" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c"
    if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "bc" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c" and STRING_STATUS is "b"
    if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "z" then NUMB is 0 and STRING_STATUS is "z"
```

1. No matter what other columns will be received except the ones mentioned here they must be removed - done

**awk code:**

```
    BEGIN {
      FS=","; OFS="\t";
      a["ODT"]=1;a["AGE"]=1;a["CDT"]=1;a["CO"]=1;
        a["SEX"]=1;a["TIME"]=1;a["VALUE"]=1;a["COMMENT"]=1;
    }
    NR==1 {


   { $a["VALUE"] = "NUMB" ; $a["COMMENT"] = "STRING_COM" ; $9 = "STRING_STATUS" ; print ; next }
    $a["VALUE"]=="14,385" && $a["COMMENT"] == "d"  { $a["VALUE"] = "14385" ; $a["COMMENT"] = $9 = "" }
    $a["VALUE"]=="14,385" && $a["COMMENT"] == "du" { $a["VALUE"] = "14385" ; $a["COMMENT"] = "" ; $9 = "u" }
    $a["VALUE"] != ":" { print ; next }
    $a["COMMENT"] == "z" { $a["VALUE"] = "0" ; $a["COMMENT"] = "" ; $9 = "z" }
     $a["COMMENT"] != "z" { $a["VALUE"] = "" }

        $NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) a[$i]=i;
    }
    {   print $a["ODT"],$a["AGE"],$a["CDT"],$a["CO"],$a["SEX"],$a["TIME"],NR==1?"NUMB":$a["VALUE"],
        NR==1?"STRING_COM"OFS"STRING_STATUS":($a["COMMENT"]?""OFS$a["COMMENT"]:$a["COMMENT"]);
    }
```

Does anyone knows how can I solve point 4?

**expected result should be**

**csv input**

```
ODT AGE CDT CO  SEX TIME    NUMB   COMMENT
P3  Y6-8    AWT EE  F   2011    1297    
P4  Y3-4    ESP RR  M   2011    6940    cd
P1  Y7-9    UDK FF  F   2011    :   du
PL  Y3-9    EUP SS  F   2011    :       d
P9  Y_5 ACT DD  F   2011    :   cd
P6  Y5-9    UAK DF  M   2011    :   z


ODT AGE CDT CO  SEX TIME    NUMB   STRING_COM       STRING_STATUS
P3  Y6-8    AWT EE  F   2011    1297    
P4  Y3-4    ESP RR  M   2011    6940    c
P1  Y7-9    UDK FF  F   2011           u
PL  Y3-9    EUP SS  F   2011        
P9  Y_5 ACT DD  F   2011        c
P6  Y5-9    UAK DF  M   2011    0      z
```

Thank you in advance

I have updated the code as you suggested but it doesn't work. only errors
is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach I would take is to add some more conditional blocks, also for the rules that are already implemented.

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","; OFS="\t";
}
NR==1 { $7 = "NUMB" ; $8 = "STRING_COM" ; $9 = "STRING_STATUS" ; print ; next }
$7=="14,385" && $8 == "d"  { $7 = "14385" ; $8 = $9 = "" }
$7=="14,385" && $8 == "du" { $7 = "14385" ; $8 = "" ; $9 = "u" }
$7 != ":" { print ; next }
$8 == "z" { $7 = "0" ; $8 = "" ; $9 = "z" }
$8 != "z" { $7 = "" }
...
{ print }
```

It may be missing something that your code has solved and that I didn't quite grasp, but this is the spirit in which I'd structure the script.

Assuming that the array `a` is supposed to accomodate for input with a jumbled order of fields, you can either

- use the array fields instead of the numbered fields or
- run a preprocessor in a pipe that will arrange the fields in the proper order

Comment: who is field $9? should I define another a["COMMENT1"] = 1; I have added your code and changing the numebrs with the array but I'm getting error. It doesn't work. could you please show the entire code integrated? I have tried but with no success:(

Comment: Field `$9` is the `STRING_STATUS` field you are newly populating. The proposal really aims at implementing your rules in a literal fashion, and cutting some corners. It will need tinkering, yes.

Comment: Well, `$a` can never work for one thing. It's just `a`, no `$` prefix. Also, I'm not sure how `STRING_COM` and `STRING_STATUS` work in your model. You will have to replace my `$9` with an approprate array expression in any case, though. I suspect you want to initialize `a["STRING_COM"]` from the comment field and `a["STRING_STATUS"]` as empty...although your actual target semantics are unclear to me.